# gtkmm 4: Make widget to vertically fill the Gtk::HeaderBar

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm4

Is it possible for a `Gtk::Widget`, say a `Gtk::Button` to fill the `Gtk::HeaderBar` completely vertically? If it is indeed possible, how is this achieved?

[image]

As seen in the above picture, there seems to be a small space between the top and bottom end of the `HeaderBar`, no matter if `Button::set_vexpand(true)`, `Button::set_margin(0)`, `HeaderBar::set_margin(0)` or `HeaderBar::set_spacing(0)` are called.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it directly. You may have to tweak the presentation using CSS. In my opinion, however, unless you have a very good reason to do this, I think it's better not "fighting" the framework.